# How do I install PHP 5.6 on Debian 7.10? (Having trouble with installation.)

Tags: debian, software-installation, php

Hi I was [following this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865553/attempting-to-install-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-14-04)

and trying to install php 5.6 on my Debian Wheezy (64 bits).

I'm doing it because I have virtualmin on my server and my php version is 5.4 and I need the 5.6 to do a backup of my wordpress through "Duplicator", however it requires me the 5.6 at least.

I was trying to install php 5.6 manually (btw I couldn't find the package libdb5.3-dev ), but when I tried to extract and move my php5.6 it gave an error.

I tried to use wget a few times and still there was always the same error.

This is the error:

```
root@ns3009614:/# tar -xvjpf /home/downloads/php-5.6.31.tar.gz -C /opt/build
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
root@ns3009614:/# tar -xvjpf /home/downloads -C /opt/build
tar (child): /home/downloads: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
        perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
        Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Could you help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a problem because you are trying to treat the `php-5.6.31.tar.gz` file as a bzip2 compressed file. While the actual file is a gzip compressed file.

Change `tar -xvjpf php-5.6.31.tar.gz` to `tar -xvzf php-5.6.31.tar.gz` and this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding the following lines:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
```

Fetch and install the GnuPG key:

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
```

Install PHP 5.6:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

More options: [Instructions on dotdeb.org](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/)